# Sql, sum rows and group by

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with php and mysql. Mysql table is this

[image]

N=name, I have projects(1,2..) and each project has many exercises. I want to get a result like this.. N(for example nick) project(1) value(the sum of exercises). 
could you help me please..

Comment: Show us what you have tried please

Comment: I think the statement you want would start with `SELECT` and have a `FROM` clause, possibly some conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Can you write a SQL `SELECT` statement that returns some detail rows from the table, without aggregation?

Comment: yes i can write a SQL SELECT statement that returns some detail rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're asking for, but it will at least give you a starting point on the sql syntax.

```
SELECT N, project_id, SUM(value) 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY N, project_id
```